# how to store and read large java objects to hardrive instead of heap memory in java

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, store, hard-drive

we have a requirement where we have to load a large volume of data which may require 150+ GB heap memory, we can't afford that much memory, tried ehcahe working fine with fast accessing but consuming more memory which we can't afford, is there a way we can store Java objects into files or hard drive and read the data quickly using any java supported api or framework(reason for asking is reduce heap memory and access data quickly, our entire data we are storing one java class with different months of data, lets take employee joining month wise data into employee class)?

Comment: Please show us the code that reads the *large volume of data* and the *one java class* you are using to store the entire data.

Comment: For EhCache it is possible to configure how many elements you store in memory. All excessive elements will be dumped to file system.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to store that data as a java object, rather than as plain data?

Comment: deHaar - querying DB and mapping data to employee class, ehcache maintains the cache based on parameter if the same parameter comes it will return from cache, parameter here is the month we are passing past 2on months

Comment: Christine - later on top of java object we need run additional logic based on user search

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8921755/ivan tried maxBytesLocalHeap="25MB" maxEntriesLocalDisk="100000" still consuming more heap